# Detecting whether file was uploaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

Wondering whether there is there a nicer way to detect whether a file was actually uploaded than this?

```
if (Request.Files["ProfileImage"].InputStream.Length > 0)
{
    newCat.ProfileImage = SaveProfileImage();
}
```

In my web page there is a file control with name "ProfileImage"

```
<input type="file" name="ProfileImage" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the `HttpPostedFile.ContentLength`, but that's pretty much the same thing.

If you were using the `<asp:FileUpload />` control, then you could access the `HasFile` property, but you're not :)